# Ionic 2: Calling Events subscribe and unsubscribe simultaneously

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2, dom-events

I am trying to use `Publish` and `Subscribe` from ionic-angular.

**subscribe.js**

```
this.events.subscribe('done:eventA', (userEventData) => {
  //Perform some operations
  this.startEventB();
  this.events.unsubscribe('done:eventA');    <---
}

this.events.subscribe('done:eventB', (userEventData) => {
  //Perform some operations
  this.startEventA();
}

this.events.subscribe('done:eventA', (userEventData) => {
  //Perform some operations
  this.startEventC();
}

startEventB(){ 
  this.events.publish('done:eventB', data);
}

startEventA(){
  this.events.publish('done:eventA', data);
}
```

The **first** time Event A is publish I want to perform `startEventB()`
The **second** time Event A is publish I want to perform `startEventC()` so I tried to `unsubscribe` from the first part.
But when I `unsubscribe`, all my subscriptions are gone.

Can I know whats a good way to subscribe and unsubscribe from events?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't pass a second parameter to the unsubscribe, all subscribers are [removed](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/8235). If you want to unsubscribe a given subscriber, you must subscribe and unsubscribe the very same object, as explained [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/events-pub-sub-how-to-unsubscribe-in-lifecycle-hook/50596/5?u=xme).

Another solution I prefer, is to share a service between the components that has one of the RxJS subject types. The source class can publish using a service function that does next on the subject, and the target class can observe the stream obtaining the subject as an observable.

Here you have an example of this kind of service:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';

import {Booking} from '../../common/model/booking';


@Injectable()
export class BookingEventsService
{
    private _newChannel: Subject<Booking> = new Subject<Booking>();


    constructor()
    {
    }

    publishNew( booking: Booking )
    {
        this._newChannel.next( booking );
    }

    newChannel(): Observable<Booking>
    {
        return this._newChannel.asObservable();
    }
}
```

Hope it helps. Regards,
Xavi